# Add and request values to/from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I created a multidimensional array like this:

```
var lang_arr = {};
$('#language li a img').each(function(index) {
    var lang_arr_helper = [];
    lang_arr_helper.push(langi);
    lang_arr_helper.push(getnumber);
    lang_arr.push(lang_arr_helper);
});
```

I want to call it with a loop afterwards:

```
for (index=0;index < lang_arr.length;++index)
{
  alert(lang_arr[index][0]+" "+lang_arr[index][1]);
}
```

It doesn't matter if array or object, so how to call it but loop required. how this is done with array and/or object?

Thanks !!

Comment: If you want an array, then create an array, not an object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections

Comment: Please indent your code correct on the left side!

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) would be a convenient way to iterate over multidimensional javascript array:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3],[42,24],[8,9,10]];

arr.forEach(function(sub,i1) {
  sub.forEach(function(item,i2) {
    console.log("["+i1+","+i2+"] = "+item);
  })
});
```

This would output

```
[0,0] = 1
[0,1] = 2
[0,2] = 3
[1,0] = 42
[1,1] = 24
[2,0] = 8
[2,1] = 9
[2,2] = 10
```

To iterate over object, use `for(key in obj)` construct, which will loop all enumerable properties.

```
var obj = {
    a:{a:1,b:2,c:3},
    b:{x:42,y:24},
    c:{u:8,v:9,w:10}
};

for(var key in obj) for(var i in obj[key]) {
  console.log("["+key+","+i+"] = "+obj[key][i]);
}
```

produces

```
[a,a] = 1
[a,b] = 2
[a,c] = 3
[b,x] = 42
[b,y] = 24
[c,u] = 8
[c,v] = 9
[c,w] = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You created an object instead of an Array. To create Arrays you should:

```
var lang_arr_helper = new Array();
```

or

```
var lang_arr_helper = {};
```

in the same way you did it the first time.

When you use `[]`, it creates an Object, which has no `.length` property to be used. That's why the for doesn't iterates through it.